# Where is the correct place to increase the number of open file descriptors for a Rabbit server?

Tags: rabbitmq

I'm trying to do everything the documentation suggests to increase RabbitMQ's `open file descriptor`, but it has no effect.

I have already made all the changes below and the result of `rabbitmqctl status` does not change.

```
sudo nano /etc/sysctl.conf
fs.file-max=1048576

sudo nano /etc/default/rabbitmq-server
ulimit -S -n 1048576

sudo nano /etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-env.conf
ulimit -S -n 1048576
#This action causes the server not to start
```

This directory and file does not exist: `/etc/systemd/system/rabbitmq-server.service.d/limits.conf`

And the result of `rabbitmqctl status` always looks like it always does:

```
File Descriptors

Total: 6, limit: 32671
Sockets: 0, limit: 29401
```

And my ulimit is like this:

```
$ulimit -Sn
1048576

$ulimit -Hn
1048576
```

OS: Ubuntu 20.04
RabbitMQ: 3.12.4

Source:

https://www.rabbitmq.com/networking.html

https://www.rabbitmq.com/configure.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `systemctl edit rabbitmq-server.service` to create an override. You can then add or change `LimitNOFILE`

---

Related discussion:

- Question - https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server/discussions/9303
- Answer: https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server/discussions/9303#discussioncomment-6926773